# Orion-LD issues no notification send to subscription

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

**Update 2**
The issues might be the use of the the Orion-LD (1.0.0), when i use the 0.8.0 all the example is working.
https://github.com/kosgobakis/orion-ldSubcription

My setup is:

- The Things Network (LoraWAN)
- IoT Agent for LoraWAN supporting TTN and NGSI-LD [GitHub](https://github.com/kosgobakis/IoTagent-LoRaWAN)
- Orion-LD
- Quantumleap + cratedb
- Minimal web server to provide JSONLD

Provision of the sensor to the IoT Agent

```
curl -iL -X POST \
localhost:4041/iot/devices \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-H 'Accept: application/json' \
-H 'fiware-service: openiot' \
-H 'fiware-servicepath: /' \
-d '{
  "devices": [
    {
      "device_id": "eui-70b3d57ed004a537",
      "entity_name": "urn:ngsi-ld:TemperatureSensor:temperaturesensor001",
      "entity_type": "LoraDevice",
      "timezone": "Europe/Athens",
      "attributes": [
        {
          "object_id": "temperature_3",
          "name": "temperatureCh3",
          "type": "Float",
          "metadata": {"unitCode": {"type": "Property","value": "CEL"}}
        },        
        {
          "object_id": "temperature_5",
          "name": "temperatureCh5",
          "type": "Float",
          "metadata": {"unitCode": {"type": "Property","value": "CEL"}}
          }
      ],
      "internal_attributes": {
        "lorawan": {
          "application_server": {
            "host": "eu1.cloud.thethings.network",
            "username": "XXXX@ttn",
            "password": "XXXX",
            "provider": "TTN"
          },
          "dev_eui": "XXXXX",
          "app_eui": "XXXXXX",
          "application_id": "XXXXXX@ttn",
          "application_key": "XXXXXX",
          "data_model": "application_server"
        }
      },
      "protocol": "LORAJSON"
    }
  ] 
}'
```

I successfully receive data from the TTN Network (Simulation of sensor at TTN->IoTAgent->Orion-LD)

```
curl -X GET 'http://localhost:1026/ngsi-ld/v1/entities/?type=LoraDevice' \
-H 'fiware-service: openiot' \
-H 'fiware-servicepath: /' \
-H 'Link: <http://context/ngsi-context.jsonld>; rel="http://www.w3.org/ns/json-ld#context"; type="application/ld+json"' \
-H 'Accept: application/json' |jq .
```

```
[
  {
    "id": "urn:ngsi-ld:TemperatureSensor:temperaturesensor001",
    "type": "LoraDevice",
    "temperatureCh3": {
      "type": "Property",
      "value": 27.2,
      "observedAt": "2022-01-04T18:54:14.447Z",
      "unitCode": "CEL"
    },
    "temperatureCh5": {
      "type": "Property",
      "value": 25.5,
      "observedAt": "2022-01-04T18:54:14.447Z",
      "unitCode": "CEL"
    }
  }
]
```

I use the following curl to create a new subscription to the Orion-LD

```
curl -L -X POST 'http://localhost:1026/ngsi-ld/v1/subscriptions/' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/ld+json' \
-H 'NGSILD-Tenant: openiot' \
--data-raw '{
  "description": "Notify me of all changes",
  "type": "Subscription",
  "entities": [{"type": "LoraDevice"}],
  "notification": {
    "attributes": ["temperatureCh3"],
    "format": "normalized",
    "endpoint": {
      "uri": "http://quantumleap:8668/v2/notify",
      "accept": "application/json"
    }
  },
   "@context": "http://context/ngsi-context.jsonld"
  }'
```

and verify that i have create the subscription

```
curl -X GET 'http://localhost:1026/ngsi-ld/v1/subscriptions/' \
  -H 'NGSILD-Tenant: openiot'|jq .

  {
    "id": "urn:ngsi-ld:Subscription:61d53fc5fb688acae04cd92f",
    "type": "Subscription",
    "description": "Notify me of all changes",
    "entities": [
      {
        "type": "LoraDevice"
      }
    ],
    "notification": {
      "attributes": [
        "temperatureCh3"
      ],
      "format": "normalized",
      "endpoint": {
        "uri": "http://quantumleap:8668/v2/notify",
        "accept": "application/json"
      }
    },
    "@context": "http://context/ngsi-context.jsonld"
  }
]
```

Send new measurement (Orion-LD log: Servicing NGSI-LD request 006: POST /ngsi-ld/v1/entityOperations/upsert/), check that the Orion-LD has the new data, but no notification send to the quantumleap

```
[
  {
    "id": "urn:ngsi-ld:TemperatureSensor:temperaturesensor001",
    "type": "LoraDevice",
    "temperatureCh3": {
      "type": "Property",
      "value": 27.3,
      "observedAt": "2022-01-05T06:53:17.572Z",
      "unitCode": "CEL"
    },
    "temperatureCh5": {
      "type": "Property",
      "value": 25.5,
      "observedAt": "2022-01-05T06:53:17.572Z",
      "unitCode": "CEL"
    }
  }
]
```

I have spend some time changing the subscription request but with no success.
Is something wrong with my subscription request?

Using MongoDB Compass here is the context of the DB
orion-openiot.entities

```
{
    "_id": {
        "id": "urn:ngsi-ld:TemperatureSensor:temperaturesensor001",
        "type": "https://ngsi-ld-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/datamodels.html#loraSensors",
        "servicePath": "/"
    },
    "attrNames": ["https://ngsi-ld-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/datamodels.html#temperature1", "https://ngsi-ld-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/datamodels.html#temperature2"],
    "attrs": {
        "https://ngsi-ld-tutorials=readthedocs=io/en/latest/datamodels=html#temperature1": {
            "value": 27.3,
            "type": "Property",
            "md": {
                "unitCode": {
                    "value": "CEL"
                },
                "observedAt": {
                    "value": 1641365597.572
                }
            },
            "mdNames": ["unitCode", "observedAt"],
            "creDate": 1641365539.6579854,
            "modDate": 1641365597.5791261
        },
        "https://ngsi-ld-tutorials=readthedocs=io/en/latest/datamodels=html#temperature2": {
            "value": 25.5,
            "type": "Property",
            "md": {
                "unitCode": {
                    "value": "CEL"
                },
                "observedAt": {
                    "value": 1641365597.572
                }
            },
            "mdNames": ["unitCode", "observedAt"],
            "creDate": 1641365539.6579854,
            "modDate": 1641365597.5791261
        }
    },
    "creDate": 1641365441.9127274,
    "modDate": 1641365597.5791261,
    "lastCorrelator": ""
}
```

orion-openiot.csubs

```
{
    "_id": "urn:ngsi-ld:Subscription:61d53fc5fb688acae04cd92f",
    "expiration": 2147483647,
    "reference": "http://quantumleap:8668/v2/notify",
    "custom": false,
    "mimeType": "application/json",
    "throttling": 0,
    "servicePath": "/",
    "description": "Notify me of all changes",
    "status": "active",
    "entities": [{
        "id": "",
        "isPattern": "",
        "type": "https://ngsi-ld-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/datamodels.html#loraSensors",
        "isTypePattern": false
    }],
    "attrs": ["https://ngsi-ld-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/datamodels.html#temperature1"],
    "metadata": [],
    "blacklist": false,
    "ldContext": "http://context/ngsi-context.jsonld",
    "createdAt": 1641365445.068897,
    "modifiedAt": 1641365445.068897,
    "conditions": [],
    "expression": {
        "q": "",
        "mq": "",
        "geometry": "",
        "coords": "",
        "georel": "",
        "geoproperty": ""
    },
    "format": "normalized"
}
```

**Update 1**

I run the latest version of the IoTAgent
`{"libVersion":"2.18.0-next","port":"4041","baseRoot":"/"}`
and a minimal web server to provide JSONLD (http://context/xxxx.jsonld)
When created a minimal jsonld file like you suggested.
The IoT Agent send the following POST to Orion-LD

```
{

    "url": "http://orion:1026/ngsi-ld/v1/entityOperations/upsert/?options=update",

    "method": "POST",

    "headers": {

        "fiware-service": "openiot",

        "fiware-servicepath": "/",

        "Content-Type": "application/ld+json",

        "NGSILD-Tenant": "openiot",

        "NGSILD-Path": "/"

    },

    "json": [

        {

            "@context": "http://context/minimal.jsonld",

            "temperatureCh3": {

                "type": "Property",

                "value": 436.8,

                "unitCode": "CEL",

                "observedAt": "2022-01-07T15:24:28.273Z"

            },

            "temperatureCh5": {

                "type": "Property",

                "value": 25.5,

                "unitCode": "CEL",

                "observedAt": "2022-01-07T15:24:28.273Z"

            },

            "id": "urn:ngsi-ld:TemperatureSensor:temperaturesensor001",

            "type": "LoraDevice"

        }

    ]

}
```

When i run

```
curl -G -X GET  'http://localhost:1026/ngsi-ld/v1/entities/urn:ngsi-ld:TemperatureSensor:temperaturesensor001' \
-H 'fiware-service: openiot' \
-H 'Link: <http://context/minimal.jsonld>; rel="http://www.w3.org/ns/json-ld#context"; type="application/ld+json"' \
-H 'Accept: application/ld+json' | jq .
```

```
{
  "@context": "http://context/minimal.jsonld",
  "id": "urn:ngsi-ld:TemperatureSensor:temperaturesensor001",
  "type": "LoraDevice",
  "temperatureCh3": {
    "value": 436.8,
    "type": "Property",
    "unitCode": "CEL",
    "observedAt": "2022-01-07T15:24:28.273Z"
  },
  "temperatureCh5": {
    "value": 25.5,
    "type": "Property",
    "unitCode": "CEL",
    "observedAt": "2022-01-07T15:24:28.273Z"
  }
}
```

And when i do not supply the correct jsonld file

```
curl -L -X GET \
   'http://localhost:1026/ngsi-ld/v1/entities/urn:ngsi-ld:TemperatureSensor:temperaturesensor001' \
   -H 'fiware-service: openiot' \
-H 'Link: <https://uri.etsi.org/ngsi-ld/v1/ngsi-ld-core-context-v1.4.jsonld>; rel="http://www.w3.org/ns/json-ld#context"; type="application/ld+json"' \
-H 'Accept: application/ld+json'| jq .
```

i get the full URI

```
{
  "@context": "https://uri.etsi.org/ngsi-ld/v1/ngsi-ld-core-context-v1.4.jsonld",
  "id": "urn:ngsi-ld:TemperatureSensor:temperaturesensor001",
  "type": "https://example.com/LoraDevice",
  "https://example.com/ch3": {
    "value": 436.8,
    "type": "Property",
    "unitCode": "CEL",
    "observedAt": "2022-01-07T15:24:28.273Z"
  },
  "https://example.com/ch5": {
    "value": 25.5,
    "type": "Property",
    "unitCode": "CEL",
    "observedAt": "2022-01-07T15:24:28.273Z"
  }
}
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to check is whether the IoT Agent version you are using is supporting NGSI-LD:

```sh
curl -X GET \
  'http://localhost:4041/iot/about'
```

Should return:

```json
{
    "libVersion": "2.6.0-next",
    "port": "4041",
    "baseRoot": "/",
    "version": "1.6.0-next"
}
```

The `lib-version` needs to be [2.15.0](https://github.com/telefonicaid/iotagent-node-lib/releases/tag/2.15.0) or higher to expose NGSI-LD support. If necessary you can rebuild a `latest` from the `Dockerfile` in the [IoTagent-LoRaWAN repo](https://github.com/Atos-Research-and-Innovation/IoTagent-LoRaWAN/blob/master/docker/) to make sure you have all the latest bug fixes from the IoT Agent node lib.

But I think the missing link here is the local [`@context` file](https://www.w3.org/TR/json-ld/#the-context) you need to provide to supply NGSI-LD data (and indeed any JSON-LD data). This file defines your world in terms of IRIs.

Your LoRaWAN IoT Agent `config.js` will need an entry to some file on a public server like:

```js
{
    contextBroker: {
        host: '192.168.1.1',
        port: '1026',
        ngsiVersion: 'ld',
        jsonLdContext: 'http://path/to/your/context.json-ld'
    },
```

Or  `IOTA_CB_NGSI_VERSION` and `IOTA_JSON_LD_CONTEXT` supplied by environment variables. The file `path/to/your/context.json-ld` will need to hold key-value entries like:

```json
{
    "@context": {
        "type": "@type",
        "id": "@id",
        "ngsi-ld": "https://uri.etsi.org/ngsi-ld/",
        "example": "https://example.com/",
        
        "LoraDevice": "example:LoraDevice",

        "temperatureCh3": "https://example.com/ch3",
        "temperatureCh5": "https://example.com/ch5"
    }
}
```

i.e. one entry for each entity `type` and one entry for each `attribute`.

It looks like your @context file is referring to `https://fiware.github.io/data-models/context.jsonld` which doesn't hold IRI values for your new property names.

When you are provisioning the subscription:

```sh
curl -X GET 'http://localhost:1026/ngsi-ld/v1/subscriptions/' \
  -H 'NGSILD-Tenant: openiot'|jq .

  {
    "id": "urn:ngsi-ld:Subscription:61d53fc5fb688acae04cd92f",
    "type": "Subscription",
    "description": "Notify me of all changes",
    "entities": [
      {
        "type": "LoraDevice"
      }
    ],
    "notification": {
      "attributes": [
        "temperatureCh3"
      ],
      "format": "normalized",
      "endpoint": {
        "uri": "http://quantumleap:8668/v2/notify",
        "accept": "application/json"
      }
    },
    "@context": "http://path/to/your/context.json-ld"
  }
]
```

The attribute names defined in `http://path/to/your/context.json-ld` are expanded to [IRIs](https://www.w3.org/TR/json-ld/#iris). If no matching entry is found then the default context `https://uri.etsi.org/ngsi-ld/default-context/` is used (as defined by the [`@vocab` element](https://www.w3.org/TR/json-ld/#default-vocabulary)) , which is not what you want. Define `temperatureCh3` and `LoraDevice` properly and the subscription will work.

As a check, try retrieving an entity without supplying any of your terms in the `@context`

```sh
curl -L -X GET \
   'http://localhost:1026/ngsi-ld/v1/entities/urn:ngsi-ld:TemperatureSensor:temperaturesensor001' \
-H 'Link: <https://uri.etsi.org/ngsi-ld/v1/ngsi-ld-core-context-v1.4.jsonld>; rel="http://www.w3.org/ns/json-ld#context"; type="application/ld+json"' \
-H 'Accept: application/ld+json'
```

All attributes (which are not defined in the core `@context`) should now return using IRIs - if short names are returned, then the relevant mapping is missing.

Comment: What does an entity without your local context return - short name for attributes or IRIs?

Comment: updates on the original question. Still no update to the Quantumleap. Updated the github repository with latest code https://github.com/kosgobakis/IoTagent-LoRaWAN

Comment: So if the data is being sent to the context broker and your `http://context/minimal.jsonld` is working - which it appears to be. The problem must lie in the subscription.

Comment: Run `curl -L -X GET 'http://localhost:1026/ngsi-ld/v1/subscriptions/' \
-H 'NGSILD-Tenant: openiot' \
-H 'fiware-servicepath: /'` to display your subscriptions -  You should be getting `timesSent` and `lastSuccess` as part of the response (assuming it has fired once)

Comment: Running `curl -L -X GET 'http://localhost:1026/ngsi-ld/v1/subscriptions/' -H 'NGSILD-Tenant: openiot' -H 'fiware-servicepath: /' ` and sending data not `timesSent` or `lastSuccess` aper in on the output. My intuition is that the problem is still in the subscription. Any thought on how to debug the subscription ?

Comment: How to debug FIWARE: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FRqJsywi9e8

Comment: Additionally, I use this [Event Monitor](https://github.com/FIWARE/tutorials.Subscriptions/tree/NGSI-LD#event-monitor-1) from the tutorials to check the contents of a subscription - within the NGSI-LD tutorial setup, you can use the `http://tutorial:3000/subscription/xxxxx` endpoint - amend the domain name if your `docker-compose` states a different `alias` or `host` for the tool.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the useful resources. After a lot of hours debugging, the issue is the latest orion-ld 1.0.0. I have created a example here [https://github.com/kosgobakis/orion-ldSubcription](https://github.com/kosgobakis/orion-ldSubcription)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce the problem, pushed a new functest to Orion-LD's develop branch for this purpose:
https://github.com/FIWARE/context.Orion-LD/pull/983

I'm unable to reproduce, so, could you please take a look at the functest I implemented (free from iot-agents, QLs, etc - just the broker, a notification receiver, and curl commands) and propose changes. See if we're able to reproduce the error. Cause if not, if I can't reproduce, then I can't fix ...

Here you can see the functest: https://github.com/FIWARE/context.Orion-LD/pull/983/files#diff-921fc6ab850278cc281e7662f6170be2e3474f95a800000779c1dd9c6c377dd6R1